# Rearranging subfields with the Address Field module

Tags: entities

Is there a way to rearrange the fields within the widget with a specific hook? Should I use `hook_form_alter()`?

To be more specific, I want to put the country field below the zip-code field when using the [Address Field](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have two solutions for it:

1. hook_field_widget_form_alter()
2. Ctools plugin

**Solution 1. hook_field_widget_form_alter().**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, $form_state, $context) {
  if(!empty($element['#addressfield'])) {
    $element['country']['#weight'] = 100;
  }
}
```

Use `$element` and `$context` arrays and implement own `IF` statement. You can find all the information about the field and user here.

**Solution 2. Ctools plugin**

It's possible with ctools plugins. Review `addressfield/plugins/format/` or https://drupal.org/project/addressfield_vn as an example.

Just add your custom plugin with addressfield alter in 5 steps:

Step 1: Create `MYMODULE/plugins/format/` folders structure.

Step 2: Add next code to your `MYMODULE.module` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ctools_plugin_directory().
 */
function MYMODULE_ctools_plugin_directory($module, $plugin) {
  if ($module == 'addressfield') {
    return 'plugins/' . $plugin;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_ctools_plugin_type().
 */
function MYMODULE_ctools_plugin_type() {
  $plugins['format'] = array(
    'load themes' => TRUE,
  );
  return $plugins;
}
```

Step 3: Add file with alter code. E.g.: `MYMODULE/plugins/format/address-alter.inc`:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Move country field to the very end.
 */

$plugin = array(
  'title' => t('Alter addressfield'),
  'format callback' => 'MYMODULE_format_address_alter_country',
  'type' => 'address',
  'weight' => -80,
);

/**
 * Format callback.
 *
 * @see CALLBACK_addressfield_format_callback()
 */
function MYMODULE_format_address_alter_country(&$format, $address, $context = array()) {
  // Move country field to the very end.
  $format['country']['#weight'] = 100;
}
```

Step 4: `drush cc all`

Step 5: Enable your plugin for addressfield in customer profile fields settings. E.g. at `/admin/commerce/customer-profiles/types/billing/fields/commerce_customer_address`

In the current example all the alter code will be inside the `MYMODULE_format_address_alter_country()` function. Just play with weights of your fields and you'll get the form rearranged.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense to keep the country field in the first place, as the other fields change depending on the selected country.

Comment: Yeah I know, unfortunately a client wants us to move the field :(

Comment: `hook_form_alter` will help you on this.

Comment: Guess Ill try today and see if I can manipulate the widget form. Though I got a feeling hook_form_alter won't work.

Comment: Yeah hook_form_alter worked fine I just had to locate the field in the array object which was deep.

Comment: @Novazero, see my update in the answer. you can use `hook_field_widget_form_alter()`.

Comment: @milkovsky Thats what I ended up using awhile back.