# Add state for Germany and drop-down menu

Tags: entities

How do you change the default fields in the addressfield Module for a given country?

For Germany you have [image: Default addressfield of Germany], while for USA you get [image], including a nice drop down menu with all 51 states.

I want to change the Germany default to have

- only one address field (only Address 1)
- a field with a drop down menu, showing the states of Germany.

I read on [drupal.stackexchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52047/rearranging-subfields-with-the-address-field-module/93795#93795) that it should be possible with hook_form_alter or with ctools module, but within 4 hours of browsing and trying, I could not figure out how?

I'm using drupal for 5 months, so I would appreciate a detailed answer, but also any short link, that helps me to solve that issue, is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure out how to change the default fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Address Field module uses a plugin system for building the address fields. You should create an address field plugin in your custom module.

[`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) wouldn't help much in this case.

To create a plugin for Address Field, you should first implement `hook_ctools_plugin_directory()` in your module to tell you have an addressfield plugin and where they live:

```
function YOURMODULE_ctools_plugin_directory($module, $plugin) {
  if ($module == 'addressfield' && $plugin == 'format') {
    return 'plugins/format';
  }
}
```

Then, create the folders `plugins/format` in your module. The folder names are up to you. Under this folder create an `.inc` file, and give it a relating name, like `german-states.inc`.

In this file, you should define a `$plugin` array, which holds the information about your plugin, including the callback function name. Then define a function which can add new form elements, edit existing form elements etc.

```
$plugin = array(
  'title' => t('German States'),
  'format callback' => 'YOURMODULE_format_german_states_generate',
  'type' => 'name',
  'weight' => 0,
);

function YOURMODULE_format_german_states_generate(&$format, $address) {
  // Add new form element for German states
  if ($address['country'] == 'DE') {
    $format['locality_block']['administrative_area'] = array(
      '#title' => t('State'),
      '#required' => TRUE, // Set this FALSE if you don't want it to be required.
      '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('state'),
        'x-autocompletetype' => 'region',
        'autocomplete' => 'region',
      ),
      '#options' => array(
        '' => t('--'),
        'BW' => t('Baden-Württemberg'),
        'BY' => t('Bavaria'),
        'BE' => t('Berlin'),
        'BB' => t('Brandenburg'),
        'HB' => t('Bremen'),
        'HH' => t('Hamburg'),
        'HE' => t('Hesse'),
        'NI' => t('Lower Saxony'),
        'MV' => t('Mecklenburg-Vorpommern'),
        'NRW' => t('North Rhine-Westphalia'),
        'RP' => t('Rhineland-Palantine'),
        'SL' => t('Saarland'),
        'SN' => t('Saxony'),
        'ST' => t('Saxony-Anhalt'),
        'SH' => t('Schleswig-Holstein'),
        'TH' => t('Thuringia'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on how to do this?

Comment: @JayHaase I've updated my answer with an example code and some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I just make a commit to a sandbox on drupal https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mordonez/1508242

This module works fine for me (France), but should work too in your case. Locality textfield is converted into a select list, dynamically populated (using geonames) after a postal code input.