# Customize drupal commerce checkout page

Tags: commerce

How do I customize Drupal commerce checkout page?  I selected shipping information, billing information and payments in the checkout form builder. But the layout the fields are customized and was wondering how to change the layout of the fields like First name, last name etc...

Comment: Do you want to do it via module programming or editing .tpl files?

Answer (score 4):

[Customize Checkout Look and Feel](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/customize-checkout-look-and-feel)

There was a recent commit that made the checkout process table-less in the Commerce Issue Que. It was reverted in favor of making such a large change to the codebase on a 2.x release. That code still exists and it's all possible using theme_ functions in your template.php

1. Go here
   `/modules/checkout/includes/commerce_checkout.pages.inc` and look for functions that start with theme_
2. Add those functions that you
   want to your template.php in your theme or a custom module
3. Change the function word "**theme**" with your theme name or module name.
4. Make an obvious change or two
5. Clear all caches and
   then go through the checkout process.

Comment: I only see theme_ function for checkout review not checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an easy way of changing the layout of the checkout pages by creating a plugin for the addressfield.
Refer this link:
[Rearranging subfields with the Address Field module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52047/rearranging-subfields-with-the-address-field-module/93795#93795)